# Options for a deck flooring on a deck that is covered by a water barrier

Tags: deck

I purchased a home with a deck. And I'm trying to figure out what to cover it with.

The deck is above an interior area that is enclosed from the elements. Unlike a normal deck made of boards for flooring where water can go through, this deck has non-permeable layer so it can keep water out of the room below. Non-permeable layer:

[image: deck floor]

Beneath the non-permeable material are boards like you would traditionally see on a deck. Looking up at the deck from below:

[image: Looking at the deck from below]

Beneath the boards is the room.

When I purchased the home, the deck had a low-pile carpet like you'd see in an office. That got wet and pretty dirty, so I removed it.

I thought about putting wood or composite deck boards on top of the non-permeable layer, but I don't know how to attach them without putting screws through the waterproof material.

How can I attach composite or wood decking on top of the non-permeable layer?

Comment: That said, you'd essentially build a deck on top of the waterproofing with sleeper joists.

Comment: I will edit the question to make it non-subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 2x4 pressure treated sleepers on flat.  Attach the composite deck boards to the sleepers.

The whole thing floats on the waterproof membrane.  Use composite shims where needed to keep sleepers flat - hopefully your non-permeable membrane is sloped away from the house.

I typically paint the surface for the pt sleepers back so that you don't see them through the composite gaps which can be fairly large.

That looks like a vinyl membrane which is good for about 10 years.  Next time go for a torch on membrane which is good for 30.

Answer (score 2):

This is normally handled in commercial work where someone plans for the long term by using sectional decking on pads.

When the roof membrane needs to be replaced, rather than it being a huge hassle because you built a deck you now need to tear out to replace the roof membrane, you just disconnect the connections between sections and pads, pick them up (because you built them of a size you could pick up) and put them out of the way while you replace the roof, then replace the pads and deck sections.

Depending on your wind exposure and what the structure is built to take for loading, you either tie the edges of the deck with cables or the pads are concrete of sufficient collective weight to keep the deck from becoming airborne by gravity alone. Typically a pad would have 4 corners of deck section on it in the middle, two at the edges (assuming normal rectangles - if you want to get cute with other polygons, the number might vary.) If you have minimal wind exposure wood alone may be sufficient.

Common to have something like rubber or rigid foam on the bottom of the pads so they don't damage the membrane. A rigid foam layer can also give you a level or barely sloped deck on top of a more steeply sloped roof, by varying the thickness of the foam.